# Removing inline style after animation is not working consistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a tabbed navigation menu, when you click an element, the child icon's original position is stored in data and the icon slides to right: 10px.

When you click an alternate element, it animates back to its data-right (original position), then should clear the right: 10px.

For some reason, I can't reliably clear that inline style.

Here is the code

```
$('ul.primary-nav >li >a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  var $i = $this.children('i');

  left = $i.offset().left;
  right = $this.outerWidth() - ( left + $i.outerWidth() );


  $('ul.primary-nav >li >a').removeClass('current')
  $i.attr('data-right', right);
  $i.css('right', right);

  $this.addClass('current');
  $i.animate({right: '10px'});

  $('ul.primary-nav >li >a').not($this).each(function(){

      $oi = $(this).children('i');

      $oi.stop().animate({ right: $oi.attr('data-right') }, 300, function _afterAnimation() {
          console.log('afterAnimation called');
          $oi.css('right', '');
      });

  });

  var $dropdown = $this.parent().children('.drop-down');

  if ($dropdown.hasClass('show')){
    url = $this.attr('href');
    window.location.href = url;
  }
  else {

    $dropdown.addClass('show');
    $('.nav-bg').show();

    $this.parent().siblings().children('.drop-down').removeClass('show');

  }

});
```

Sometimes the right style clears, and other times it does not. Any ideas?

Comment: It would be awesome if you can setup a jsfiddle.net ;)

Comment: Just a quick question, is there a reason you need to use jQuery animation :)? Perhaps a CSS animate would work better, with jQuery toggleClass support?

Comment: I had to use jQuery, because I'm going from right auto, to right 0.